# Django testing post request with multipart/form data and a dictionary

Tags: python, django, integration-testing, multipartform-data

My client uses the requests library to make this call to my Django server

```
import requests
response = requests.post(url, files=dict({
            'value': 'key',
        }))
```

This will create a requests that inserts the dictionary into the field `request.FILES` as a `<MultiValueDict: {}>`

I am trying to recreate this with `django.test`.
I keep seeing to try something like

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
client = Client()
response = client.post('/sign', dict(request_data))
```

but the `request.FILES` object is empty

edit ----
I have also tried with the same result ( `request.FILES -> <MultiValueDict: {}>`)

```
client.post('/sign', {'file': dict({
  'key' : 'value'
})})
```

Edit 2---

A look at the midldleware where I am checking the value

```
class ApiAuthenticationMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request: HttpRequest):
        print(request.FILES)
```

Comment: No, I tried that as well.  The dictionary at request.FILES is still empty when you do that

Comment: updated the post with request_data

Comment: Same result - 

`client.post('/sign', **{'file': dict({'key': 'value'})})`

Comment: added more context in an edit

Comment: this contains many answers. reading all of them might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170425/how-to-unit-test-file-upload-in-django

Comment: try with this URL with an ending slash `/sign/`

Comment: Same result
`response = self.client.post('/sign/', **{'file': dict({'key': 'value'})})`

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to use the `requests` library for a Django integration test?

(I am new to Django)

Comment: try reading this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/

Answer (score -1):

Solution

```
        fake_file.name = 'data.json'
        post_data = {
            'data.json': fake_file,
        }
        return self.client.post('/sign', post_data,  content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT)
```