# How to simulate Django file submissions to forms for unittests?

Tags: python, django

I am doing a Django project where a user uploads a file to my website and then a program takes that data and assigns it to a model. I am attempting to be a good little programmer and test my code as I go, but I appear to have run into a testing issue.

One thing I want to do is limit the file types that the user can upload to .xls files. I wrote a test for this and submit the file to the form like so `self.form = self.form({'file' : good_file})`. I overrode the `clean_file()` method that the form uses to to look at the extension and raise a validation error if it's not in the approved file type list. I tried following the example posted here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/ and pulling the file from `cleaned_data['file']` but all that is there for file is `'file' : None`. However when I test a view redirecting to a different page when the user uploads a file like so `response = self.client.post('/teacher/add_course', data={'file' : open(file)})` I see the file in `clean_file()` as `'file' : InMemoryUploadedFile`.

So basically I didn't submit the file right in the form test or at least didn't give it to the form in the way that the view did. Can yall tell me what I need to be doing differently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to unit test file upload in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170425/how-to-unit-test-file-upload-in-django)

Comment: unfortunately no, I use that for testing the view, but the form seems to be different! While I could indirectly test it that way, it would break the rule of isolation I think

Comment: Form submission is in this case browser doing POST request ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) , nothing different than ordinary post except you pass file as parameter using enctype="multipart/form-data" which client.post  would automatically encode for you

Comment: hmm, so I might need to somehow add that in too?