# Testing a view that uses TemporaryUploadedFile

Tags: python, django

I have a view that does this:

```
import pandas as pd

def ingest(request):
    for temp_file in request.FILES.values():
        # There only ever is one use next(gen) if you prefer
        path = temp_file.temporary_file_path()
        break
    
   df = pd.read_csv( path, encoding="UTF-16-le", header=None )

   ...
```

And I'd like to test this view. I can't actually change the view logic as it is designed to be the endpoint fpr an external service that I have no control over.

I've added  `FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',]` to the settings to avoid nasty surprises, but I can't make the tests work.

My `test.py` :

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import TemporaryUploadedFile
from django.test import TestCase

class InputTest(TestCase):
    def test_extract_csv(self):
        form_data = {
            'upload_file': TemporaryUploadedFile("data/test.csv", "csv", 88614, "utf-16-le")
        }

        self.client.post("/ingest", form_data)
```

but that results in empty data in the view.

Comment: Does [how to unit test file upload in django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11170425/1324033) help?

Comment: I had tried the SimpleUpload answer as that is the highest rated one, and as SimpleUpload is a Subclass of MemoryUpload that had lead to the extra settings change and no success, but the accepted answer worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170472/4895724