# How to test file upload in pytest?

Tags: python, django, pytest

How to serializer a file object while using json.dumps ?

I 'm using pytest for testing file upload in django and I 've this function

```
def test_file_upload(self):
     # file_content is a bytest object
     request = client.patch(
        "/fake-url/",
        json.dumps({"file" : file_content}),
        content_type="application/json",
    )
```

I 've tried to set the `file_content` as a bytes object but I 'm getting this error `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable` I need to send the whole file to my endpoint as json serialized

Comment: File bytes cannot be serialized to JSON. What is your backend expecting ? A multipart form/data or the file encoded as a base64 string ?

Comment: the file is encoded as base64 @May.D

Comment: So just base64 encode `file_content` and you should be fine.

Comment: I tried this but still have same error I tried to use `file = base64.b64encode(file_content)` and send file instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use it mock library for testing file upload;

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from django.core.files import File

mock_image = MagicMock(file=File)
mock_image.name="sample.png"

# Another test operations...

def test_file_upload(self):
     # file_content is a bytest object
     request = client.patch(
        "/fake-url/",
        {"file" : mock_image},
        format="multipart",
    )
```

Detailed another answer; [how to unit test file upload in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170425/how-to-unit-test-file-upload-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

Your API endpoint expects a multipart form containing file. Below is the function I use to send a multipart form from a local file for testing. If you already have file bytes, skip the `open` line and just use `file_content` in `ContentFile`.

```
def send_multipart_form(self, filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        file_data = ContentFile(f.read(), os.path.basename(filename))
        res = self.client.put(
            self.url,
            data=encode_multipart(boundary=BOUNDARY, data={"file": file_data}),
            content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT,
        )
        return res
```

Comment: I tried this but for same reason it returns `400` error but works well while trying to update another field other than the file

Comment: What error message do you get with the 400 error ?

Comment: It doesn't show up the whole error but all I 'm using is just django rest framework view and serializer for my model  @May.D

Comment: If file is a FileField in your model, it does not expect a base64 string. You need to send a multipart form with your file.

Comment: Yes it's a filefield in django model , how to send a multipart ?